# Limit on child records

Tags: lookup, validation, limits

If I have two objects with lookup.
How I can limit quantity of children records to 1.

For example `Apple->Worm` objects
Create one worm, and forbid creating record in `Worm`.

How resolve this problem?

Comment: I realize you may not be a native speaker, but the plural of child is children. There is no such word as childs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're asking about look-up relationships here, not M-D relationships, my preference for this type of situation is to use workflow. I never use code when something can be done using clicks.

First we add a couple of additional fields to the object. One is `ParentId__c` which is a text field containing the `ParentId` of the of the Parent record (the field will also appear on the parent record but will be empty). The next field is `HasChild__c` which is a boolean checkbox that's used to tell us whether or not the record has a child. If false (the default value), the record has no children. Using this technique, one can have many levels of parent-children.

Optionally, it's a good idea to also add a 3rd field we'll call `ChildId__c` which gets populated with the `childRecordId`.

**Validation Rules**

We now need a validation rule on all new records to test to see whether or not it's parent record's `HasChild__c` field value is false. If it's not, then we can't create the record. This rule should look something like:

```
AND(IsNew(),Parent.HasChild__c = true)
```

We also need a workflow rule that sets `Parent.HasChild__c = true` and optionally if you use it, sets `Parent.ChildId__c = Id`.

Additionally, workflow needs to be added that when a record is deleted, the `Parent.ChildId__c` is set to `isBlank()` and `Parent.HasChild__c = false`. The latter is often more easily done with a before delete trigger than with workflow but it's essential that it happen.

Any undelete record operations will need to check for new child records that have been created in the interim before allow the record to be restored.

Comment: Nice solution for when you only care about whether or not there are records. It's a Boolean system so use a checkbox. Makes sense. Don't forget though, since the relationship is not M/D, you can only update via `Process Builder`.

Comment: That's correct on PB. In the past, I've done this primarily using combo of triggers and workflow. Only M-D can be done using workflow since you can't do the VLookup.

Answer (score 4):

If Apple is the master in a master- detail relationship with Worm, you can build a Rollup Summary field on Apple that counts the number of Worms on an Apple, then make a validation rule on Apple that limits Worm records to 1:

Validation Rule:

```
NumberOfWorms__c > 1
```

Comment: Worth mentioning dlrs.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement is to crate a one to one relationship between Parent and child object. This could have been possible if Salesforce has provided ability to create unique attribute on the lookup values like it is in SQL.

Workaround

**1. Lookup Relationship :**

- Create a Unique Text field(Say ParentIdText__c) on Child Object(Make sure to check unique checkbox while creating text field.)
- Create a workflow rule with field upate action to populate ParentIdText__c value with the value from lookup field.
- While creating workflow set Evaluation Criteria: created, and every time it’s edited.

This is it. Parent object will never have more than one child records

### Going further

> Unique in multiple lookups(Parent Objects) :

Using this method we can set the unique child record based on more than 1 parent object.
  Just set field update in above workflow rule like

```
ParentIdText__c = Parent1Id + Parent2Id + ... + Parent2Id
```

**2. Master-detail relationship :** 
    - For master detail relationship things are bit simpler and are already explained by sfdcfox in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

We can write trigger or build flow.
In that trigger/flow we can query if there are any records of related object that we are creating.

For ex. 
When you create new **Worm** record named "worm 1" which is related with **Apple** record named "Apple 1" then:

In Before trigger check if there are any **Worm** record which is related with  "Apple 1"

If yes => then throw error

In not  => continue with rest of processing.